# How to make GRUB boot for both UEFI and Legacy on a portable Ubuntu install?

Tags: grub2, uefi, 22.04

as per the title, I want to see how I can make GRUB boot both UEFI and Legacy modes, as I'm currently working on a portable install of Ubuntu on a portable SSD drive I bought.

I do have a Legacy machine, a Lenovo ThinkPad that I locked myself out of its BIOS so it's stuck on Legacy mode, currently running Linux Mint.

How do I do that? the rest of my machines are all UEFI, but my laptop and station can be changed to Legacy mode.

Drive info:
`Make: Transcend`
`Model: ESD230C`
`Size: 480GB`
`Connection: USB 3.1 Type C`

Thanks again!

Comment: You'll need to install *both* the BIOS-mode *and* the EFI-mode versions of GRUB. Beyond that I can't be of much help, since I've never before done this.

Comment: Full install to flash drive UEFI or BIOS, gpt drive - C.S.Cameron 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-19-10-to-usb-device-step-by-step You can also search for other posts by C.S.Cameron or sudodus for more info.

Comment: So I just run the installer and have a GPT format and just hope that the Legacy machine can boot GPT drives?

Comment: A *true* legacy BIOS doesn't know anything about the partition table type; it just reads the first sector of the disk and then executes the code it finds there. Trouble sometimes arises with the CSM/legacy mode in EFIs, which may try to read an interpret the GPT data before this happens; but such computers should be able to boot in EFI mode. See [here](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html) for more on this topic.

Comment: Huh. Thanks Rod!